# How to get consumer group id of a consumer from topic and partition in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to implement circuit breaker where in my error handler of kafka sends an event containing topic and partition of the consumer that caused the error. I want to get the consumer group id of that consumer and stop all the consumers belonging to that group id.

I have already explored docs but I am not getting the right set of information to go about it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What's stopping you from getting `spring.kafka.consumer.group-id`? A topic and a partition alone have no relation to the consumer group... In fact, multiple groups could read the same partition

Comment: See the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#listener-group-id

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#listener-group-id

You can either use `KafkaUtils.getConsumerGroupId()` to get the group from a `ThreadLocal` or you can add the group as a method parameter.

```java
@KafkaListener(id = "bar", topics "foo")
public void listener(@Payload String foo,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.GROUP_ID) String groupId) {
...
}
```

There is a bug in the documentation; there is no `exposeGroupId` property.